# Google Oauth 2.0 with Non web application(Windwos/Mobile app) shows Have offline access consent screen

Tags: google-oauth

We are implementing Google Oauth2.0 Single Sign On with our applications. We have Web application, windows desktop app, Adroid app, iPhone app.

From our applications(windows app/mobile app) when user tries to login we use below flow:

1) We get URL(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&login_hint=myemail@gmail.com) from our API which redirect user to Google login screen

2) After authentication:

```
a) On first login it display consent screen with scopes(View your email address/View your basic info/Know who you are on Google) mentioned in above URL.

b) On subsequent login it display consent screen with scope (Have offline access).
```

3) Then Google return us a code in page title which we use for our authentication and then we allow user to access our application.

When we are using Same flow in Web application it won't ask Offline access scope screen for subsequent logins but in Desktop app/Mobile app for all the subsequent login it ask "Have offline access" scope screen.

How can I avoid scope (Have offline access) screen for subsequent login?

Please suggest.

FYI
1) I have tried approval_prompt, access_type but no change in nature.

2) We are not storing any refresh token after first authentication.

Comment: Just curios are you using Googles .net client lib? if so how did you add login_hint?  try and remove the profile scope I think that's the one that adds offline access.

Comment: No Luck after removal of profile scope still behavior is same. Here is my new URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=xxxxxxx&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&login_hint=myemail@gmail.com

Comment: BTW I am calling direct Google API not using .NET client lib.